# How to correctly resolve promise in a mongoDB call?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to read data from a mongoDB. Ultimately I want the data retrieved from the DB to be in json formate. My currently function goes as:

```
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })

const getdata = async (): Promise<string[]> => {
  let alldata: string[]
  try {
    await client.connect()

    const database = client.db('data')
    const collection = database.collection('datacollection')

    const cursor = collection.find({ type: 'featureName' })
    alldata = await cursor.toArray()
    //console.log(alldata) //This correctly sends the required data to the console.
  } finally {
    void client.close()
  }
  //console.log(alldata) //This correctly sends the required data to the console.
  return alldata 
}

const data = getdata()

console.log(data) // this sends a "Promise { pending }"
```

I am new to javascript/typescript, but I thought that I was doing all the correct things with an asyc function and the await's -> but that clearly is not the case. Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is returning a `Promise` so you need to use `promise.then`.

E.g.

```
getData().then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Take a look at the Promise documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Understood. However if I change  `console.log(data)` to a `return data` and insert a `const d = ` before the `getData()` line. I still have the same issue where `d` is still a pending promise.

Comment: Yes, `d` would be a pending promise. You can only access the returned value from inside `then((data) => ... )`

Comment: Is there not a way to get the returned value to outside the `then(...`?